# Access Frontend's Userinformation in Backend (JavaEE)

Tags: jakarta-ee, vaadin, frontend, cdi, backend

I want to access general Userinformation (like Username, Firstname, Lastname, etc.) in my Application's Backend.

I have a multi-module setup which looks something like this:

- Mod: API - Business Logic Interfaces.
- Mod: CORE - Business Logic implementations.
- Mod: UI - Vaadin Frontend (with JavaEE & CDI Framework)
- Mod: EJB - Business Logic EJB's (also implement from API)

My Core implementation Module contains basically all Database-Interaction Services like "UserService" which updates Userinformations in the DB.
These Service Classes are Effectifely `@javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped` CDI Beans which inject the EntityManager through a ProducerClass, which is - since there's only One EntityManager PER THREAD - `@javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped`.

Now here it gets tricky ...

In some Service implementations I need to have access to Userinformations about the currently interacting user. But because the UI can have multiple Sessions and multiple Threads active I cannot simply inject those informations through a Producer Method ...

Right now I want to know if anybody ever had a similar problem (i believe so ...) and if, how did you solve it?

I thought of passing some Principal Implementation in each Method as a parameter, which is not a very beautiful - but secure way to get rid of this problem.

I HAVE to be sure that the user informations that I use in the Backend are EXACTLY the Credentials of the User that invoked the Backend service - there could be more users active at the same time, invoking the same service ...

If anybody has a good an clean solution for this problem, pleeeease let me know!

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: What about a `@RequestScoped` bean?

Comment: I thought more about a `@SessionScoped` bean, but It's a bit of a problem if you also wan't to use the core services through a jbatch ... I think I forgot that part in my question... because in a jbatch there's effectively and of course per definition no Session Scope... the RequestScoped Bean won't guarantee the correct UserInformation I think ...

Comment: You should detail a little bit  more the jbatch part ;-)

Comment: And yes i wanted to say `@SessionScoped`, sorry for the mistake

Comment: No Prob, we are all mistaking sometimes ;-)

Comment: Yea - The Point is, that I have a sort of "Migration" Module, which is currently used to generate sample data for the Application, so I don't have to create all my entities manually when I re-do the Database... For this purpose I am using the apache batchee jbatch implementation! Which works pretty nice with some hacking for the transaction management, but my problem is that I cannot inject a @SessionScoped Bean in my Core when I use the bacht module - because there's currently no SessionScope active - which is per definition correctly, but also makes me troubles ... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯